# Delphi: How can I reset all class fields to zero value?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a class with many numeric fields, number of fields will grow up with project development, so would be nice to have a way to reset all fields, no matter how many will be added in future.

```
 TParams = class
  public
    defined:  boolean;
    FirstValue:             byte; // reset from here
    A0:       single; 
    A1:       single; 
    H1:       TPoint;
       // ...............
    A100:     single; 
    LastValue:             byte; // to here
    procedure Reset;
  end;
```

The only idea comes to mind is to insert 2 fields: before and after block that should be reseted, and use FillMemory:

```
procedure TParams.Reset;
begin
  FillMemory(@FirstValue, Integer(@LastValue)-Integer(@FirstValue),0);
end;
```

Is there better way ? (Im using Delphi 7)

Comment: Put all the fields in a record and zeroise the record. Don't use an ugly hack like this.

Comment: Zeroizing won't finalize any "managed" members. If there are only numeric fields, then zeroizing is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David Heffernan already said it: what you are doing is an ugly hack, and not very clean. He also gave the hint: Turn your numeric fields into a record:

```
type
  TParams = class
  public
    Defined: Boolean;
    Numbers: record
      A0: Single;
      A1: Single;
      H1: TPoint;
      A100: Single;
    end;
    procedure Reset;
  end;
```

Now it is very simple, you can `Reset` by doing the following:

```
procedure TParams.Reset;
begin
  FillChar(Numbers, SizeOf(Numbers), 0);
end;
```

A simple test:

```
procedure Test;
var
  P: TParams;
begin
  P := TParams.Create;
  try
    Writeln(Format('%f %f (%d, %d) %f', [P.Numbers.A0, P.Numbers.A1, P.Numbers.H1.X, P.Numbers.H1.Y, P.Numbers.A100]));
    P.Numbers.A0 := 1.0;
    P.Numbers.A1 := 2.0;
    P.Numbers.H1 := Point(11, 22);
    P.Numbers.A100 := 77.0;
    Writeln(Format('%f %f (%d, %d) %f', [P.Numbers.A0, P.Numbers.A1, P.Numbers.H1.X, P.Numbers.H1.Y, P.Numbers.A100]));
    P.Reset;
    Writeln(Format('%f %f (%d, %d) %f', [P.Numbers.A0, P.Numbers.A1, P.Numbers.H1.X, P.Numbers.H1.Y, P.Numbers.A100]));
  finally
    P.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This produces the following output:

```
0.00 0.00 (0, 0) 0.00
1.00 2.00 (11, 22) 77.00
0.00 0.00 (0, 0) 0.00
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
  TNumbers = record
    A0: Single;
    A1: Single;
    H1: TPoint;
    A100: Single;
  end;

  TParams = class
  public
    Defined: Boolean;
    Numbers: TNumbers;
    procedure Reset;
  end;
```

For those with a version with generics (I know you are using Delphi 7, which has no generics, but anyway, for others), that will simplify `Reset` a little:

```
procedure TParams.Reset;
begin
  Numbers := Default(TNumbers);
end;
```

`Default` has the advantage that it will properly finalize and initialize the record, just in case it has managed types (strings, interfaces, etc.) in it.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that fiedls could be packed into record, just though there is some way not to do that.. Now i know there is no other way:)

Comment: I agree that not putting them in a record would be more convenient, because you could immediately access them as `P.A0` etc., instead of `P.Numbers.A0`. But apart from initializing all fields separately (no biggie if there are only a few, although you could forget to set one if you added a field), the record is the only clean solution. And once you can upgrade to a modern version of Delphi, use the even cleaner `Default`, instead of `ZeroMemory` or `FillChar` or similar.

Comment: FWIW, instead of using marker *bytes* like FirstValue and LastValue, you could have used two empty records ("FirstValue: record end;"). ;-) But honestly, putting the nunbers in their own record is the clean solution.

Comment: Your concern about finalising managed types can be addressed by changing the `Reset` method to `Finalize(Numbers)` before calling `FillChar`.

Answer (score 2):

In some restricted scenarios like your case with `TParams` is, a call to InitInstance should do the trick:

```
procedure TParams.Reset;
begin
  InitInstance(Self);
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't calling `InitInstance` also set his `defined` field back to `False`? OP is not trying to reset all the class fields but only some of them.

Comment: @SilverWarior, yes it would. I have no knowledge if this is desired. I am only referring to the part "to have a way to reset all fields" of the question. BTW, it will also fail if there are fields of managed types.